# PHP Percentages dealing with 0%

Tags: php

I'm kind of new to PHP I know more HTML and Obj-C.

I have my PHP script count the number of registered users who are male in the database and want to display the percentage of males from females. This is the code I currently have:

```
$percent = number_format(($male_count * 100) / $total_users); 
echo $percent;
```

That works fine, The issue that I have is if the value of $male_count is 0 I get an error message but what I want it to do is display `0%`

How do I do this?

Comment: What is your error message ?

Comment: The error message (which you should *please* always quote) is probably "division by zero" - in that case, check whether $total_users is zero first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't get an error if `$male_count` is zero. You'll probably get one if `$total_users` is zero.

How you handle that depends on what value you want in that case. Any amount between 0 and 100 is probably valid but let's assume you want 0 (code is formatted for readability):

```
$percent = number_format(
    $total_users == 0
        ? 0
        : $male_count * 100 / $total_users
);
echo $percent;
```

Alternatively, provide a function which basically works out the percentage for you, with a suitable default value if the count is zero, something like:

```
function percentage($num,$den,$def) {
    if ($den == 0) return $def;
    return $num * 100 / $den;
}

$percent = percentage($male_count,$total_users,0);
echo $percent;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$num = $total_users > 0 ? (($male_count * 100) / $total_users) : 0
$percent = number_format($num); 
echo $percent;
```

Basically a ternary if, `$total_users` is greater than 0 then divide, otherwise just use 0

Answer (score 1):

for beginners use this:

```
if($male_count == 0)
{
   echo "0%";
}
else
{
   $percent = number_format(($male_count * 100) / $total_users); 
   echo $percent; 
}
```

its a readable code., if you use shortcuts for if its ok too